# How to replace mySQL query fields with count keyword?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, preg-replace

I have to replace mysql columns using php preg_replace function is it possible to do it.
fields are not consistent any thing can be there like * or any number of fields.

example  :-

```
query1 : Select * from user;
query2 : Select fname,lname,email from user;
query3 : Select a.*,b.col1,b.col2 from user as a left join table2 as b where a.id = b.userid;
```

After replacement query should be like :

```
query1 : Select count from user;
query2 : Select count from user;
query3 : Select count from user as a left join table2 as b where a.id = b.userid;
```

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps you want `COUNT(*)`, not simply `count`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_replace` is pretty straightforward to use, it simply accepts a pattern, a string to replace the pattern with and subject text as parameters, it returns the manipulated string:

```
<?php

$query1 = <<<SQL
    Select * from user;
SQL;
$query2 = <<<SQL
    Select fname,lname,email from user;
SQL;
$query3 = <<<SQL
    Select a.*,b.col1,b.col2 from user as a left join table2 as b where a.id = b.userid;
SQL;

$query1 = preg_replace('/Select .* from/', 'Select count from', $query1);
$query2 = preg_replace('/Select .* from/', 'Select count from', $query2);
$query3 = preg_replace('/Select .* from/', 'Select count from', $query3);

/* the manipulated strings are now assigned to these variables, echo to view them */

echo $query1 . PHP_EOL;
echo $query2 . PHP_EOL;
echo $query3 . PHP_EOL;
```

output (in a terminal)

```
% php test.php
        Select count from user;
        Select count from user;
        Select count from user as a left join table2 as b where a.id = b.userid;
```

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I want. But I didnot get why my question is negative marking.